# Azure application key replacement in app service

Tags: authentication, key, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have similar question that was posted earlier in [No application keys for Azure Mobile Apps - what's a simple replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506820/no-application-keys-for-azure-mobile-apps-whats-a-simple-replacement).
But there doesn't seem to be any satisfying answer on that issue.

I just want to restrict the access to the the azure custom api & db tables with a simple key/code in my mobile client application. I dont want the users to be forced to login to their fb/google etc accounts. 
The "new" app service/mobile app seems only to work with authentication where the user/client sign in using google/fb . 
Is there any way to accomplish the "old" application key behaviour in this "new" app service?

Comment: The application key is not needed to configure in back-end application. And I could not find any related constructed function that use application key in the class 'MobileServiceClient'. I find an article that we can use custom authentication for your application, see details: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk.md#custom-auth. I think if it is possible we could use a default user  to get the credential directory without login.

Answer (score 1):

The application key was removed as it does not provide any real security. If you are using the Node.js backend, check out https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/api-key.

Comment: That seem to be exactly what i was looking for. Clear and simple example.  Thanks!!